# Why was the person who passed the sentence in the Season 7 finale not also the executioner?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the Season 7 finale of Game of Thrones, *The Dragon and the Wolf*

> Petyr Baelish is sentenced to death by Sansa, and Arya kills him

According to the old way, *The man who passes the sentence should swing the sword*

So, why did the person who passed the sentence not carry it out?

Comment: I believe the saying is "The man who passes the Sentence should swing the sword.". Sansa is evidently not a man

Comment: @Aegon pretty sure Arya is not a man too, but I see your point

Comment: Sansa didn't have a chance to kill him because Arya was too quick on the draw.

Comment: @Aegon: “Sansa is evidently not a man” — Sorry, I’ll need to see proof of that.

Comment: @Kepotx Arya is a different case. She has never said she was a lady, much like Brienne. She's a sword, as Syrio said. But she has never let her femininity get in the way of her martial nature, unlike Sansa, who has never so much as used a knife. I didn't watch the episode so can't comment on exact circumstances

Comment: Another pop up: Sansa is more acostumed to sourthon laws than the old ways

Comment: Vaguely relevant notes: neither Sansa nor Arya were present when Ned said that to Bran; and as we saw with Theon in season 2, if you’re no good at beheading someone, it’s kinder to them if you let someone else do it.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite but Sansa did see the lesson first hand when Ned told Robert he should have to kill Lady, but then decided since the wolf is of the north, a northerner should do it.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite that is a custom of all Firstmen. Sansa and Arya didn't need to be there to learn that. They could have learnt about it from anywhere else. Ned educating Bran is however a Lord educating his spare (Since Robb was the heir).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Bran know that it's the old way, even if it was his first execution. You don't have to see an execution to know the tradition

Comment: @Sooba, Aegon and Kepotx — true, although it did seem like the daughters of lords would be taught about, and expected to focus on, stuff other than the details of executions.

Comment: Also, the whole thing was planned. Even if we consider that both Sansa and Arya don't had education to rule, they can ask advice to the lords who are there. Plus, Bran was also there, and he have been taught about this.

Comment: I always interpreted that saying as a lesson or rule to live by, not necessarily a law to be followed. If she decided it was better to have someone else do the dirty work of passing the sword there's no reason she can't have that done.

Comment: There's also the fact that Sansa had not been trained with a sword, while Arya had, and using a knife to cut a throat is different than cutting meat on a plate. Arya would be able to do it easier and cleaner than Sansa ever could.

Comment: I always interpreted it as part of Ned's personal code of honor, not some law, or even commonly held belief.  It is part of what made Ned special, and set him apart from the other Lord's.

Comment: Clearly the issue is that Sansa is too small to swing a greatsword.

Comment: Just watched again and Sansa doesn't even announce a sentence to the group prior to Arya swinging the sword....

Comment: @aynber "Arya would be able to do it easier and cleaner than Sansa ever could." That was hardly easy nor clean. Suitably dramatic.

Comment: @Luke Well, it seemed easy. It was messy, but the cut itself was clean and not a hack job.

Comment: What're you guys talking about?  No-one killed Baelish. . . ;)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

> I assume that Sansa and Arya are aware of Ned's wise words. The Winterfell plot line this season has been centered around Littlefinger sowing discord amongst the Stark siblings.

However, Littlefinger's final scene shows Arya, Sansa, and Bran coming together to pass judgment on Lord Baelish. Over the past several episodes all 3 siblings had touched the dagger. They've held it and passed it between each other.

> So while Sansa might have said the words and Arya's hand was on the blade when it killed Littlefinger they operated together as a unit. The Starks did pass the sentence and the Starks swung the sword.

Comment: Pretty much my thoughts when watching the episode/recalling this quote - I also figured in a metaphorical sense Arya IS the sword in this scene.

Comment: +1 "When the cold winds blow the lone wolf dies and the pack survives." Guess who was the lone wolf there facing against the pack.

Comment: In a sense, they are **judge** (Bran - vouching for truth due to greensight), **jury** (Sansa - passing the sentence) and **executioner** (Arya - obviously).

Comment: @Cat'r'pillar. I saw that as well. I thought that part of the whole setup was Sansa showing off her powerful new killing tool (Arya) to the other lords. Everyone had seen Arya train at that point, but no one knew if it was all dancing or if she could actually deliver the killing stroke. The result of the trial helped bolster the survivors' loyalty.

Comment: @Flater I think Bran would be the jury (deciding innocence/guilt) and Sansa the judge (passing the sentence).

Comment: @Reid: Going by modern standards, a judge is tasked with making sure the trial proceeds correctly (= Bran's factchecking). You could also just argue that Bran is an witness and nothing more. The analogy wasn't meant to be legally accurate, but rather to showcase the point that Bran, Sansa and Arya "passed the sentence and wielded the sword" together (as per Ned's words). It just would've looked silly for them to finish eachother's sentences and then hold a dagger together.

Answer (score 39):

### Sansa was never taught this.

This lesson was likely never taught to Sansa or Arya to begin with. In the original scene, the lesson was for the benefit of the male children present (Robb, Jon, Bran). Given the attitudes towards what was proper for women to learn, he would not have bothered teaching this bit of wisdom to either Sansa or Arya (though Arya might have heard about it secondhand).

Sansa would have no reason to want to strike the blow herself. In addition, she has been learning, the hard way, the art of manipulation. It would fit with both this change in her personality, as well as her upbringing as a lady to let another hand do the dirty work.

She *may* have become aware of this later, but not likely - it's not the sort of thing that would come up in conversation before she was spirited away by Littlefinger, and it *certainly* was not among the behaviors he was trying to teach her. If she has not had occasion to pass this sentence on someone, there is zero reason for anyone to mention it. Certainly no one had the temerity to bring up at that moment.

Think of where she began, and where she is now. That sort of thinking belongs to the bright, honorable world she was expecting long ago when Robert and friends first came to town, a world view that has long since been shattered. Even if she IS aware of the tradition, it belongs to a world that must appear to her as naive and fanciful, where people do the right and honorable thing. she's seen what happens to people that think that way.

Whether she knows of it or not, she has no reason to do the deed herself.

Comment: Sansa is in charge of the North during the absence of Jon, and it's a tradition, so I'm not sure that she didn't know

Comment: It wasn't something she was taught when she was younger, and it's unlikely that other families held to this tradition. There would be no reason for anyone to point it out to her up to this moment, and it would take a very brave person to pipe up at that point to interject with it.

Comment: I would point out that, despite Jon likely being taught the old ways of carrying out a sentence, he executed Ramsay Bolton using Ramsay's hounds (an execution at which Sansa was present). That's not really following "the old ways" either (unless there are additional old ways laws governing poetic justice).

Comment: The Stark children seem to have pretty much abandoned Dad's way of thinking, especially our favorite little Murder Machine.

Comment: @ConjureFlyingFoxes I thought it was Sansa who released the hounds on Ramsay. Jon just locked him up.

Comment: It was Ned's code but clearly only applied in a world where men would be giving judgment and passing sentences. Of course in times of war, or for other reasons, a woman, or even a child might be nominally in charge but only until the real Lord returned. It would be perfectly acceptable for them to use a headsman, even under Ned's code, because they're only proxies themselves.

Answer (score 16):

As you say, the old way was *The man who passes the sentence **should** swing the sword* (emphasis mine). There is no natural law of the universe that prevents someone else carrying out the sentence, which is what happened in this case.

Answer (score 4):

There is two quotes at work here.

"The Man who passes the sentence should swing the sword"

and

"The lone wolf dies, but the pack survives."

The event in question symbolizes that the Stark children aren't lone wolves anymore, but they are a pack again. And the "man" (or rather the entity) that passes the sentence is the wolf pack. Thus Bran, Sansa, and Arya are all one in respect to the first quote.

Answer (score 1):

I like to think that Arya added Baelish to her list once Bran told her that he was responsible for their father's death (assuming this happened behind the scenes) and therefore wanted to be the one to end his life.